# How to create a global function that affects all or specific UIButton instance types?

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift-extensions

I want to create a global function that affects either all UIButton instances or only those of a certain UIButton type which would update the corner radius or border property.  I'm familiar with UIAppearances however my client would like to have a global file where they could update changes on the fly as if it were a CSS stylesheet.  So far I've been able to make extensions of UIColor and UIFont which returns specific colors and fonts however I can't figure out how this would work for UIButton instances.  Here is what I've thought of so far however I don't think this would work:

```
@objc extension UIButton {

    func changeUIButtonBorder() -> UIButton {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        return self
    }

}
```

Comment: what about creating a subclass and assign it to all classes ??

Comment: Yes I was thinking that as well.  However, how would I affect all instances of that subclass with one method call to change the (i.e. corner radius)? @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is great, and it *does* work for UIButton instances. But there is no need to *return* anything. In the extension, `self` *is* the button. So it can just change itself.

```
@objc extension UIButton {
    func changeUIButtonBorder() {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}
```

You can now call `changeUIButtonBorder` on *any* UIButton instance.

```
@IBOutlet var myButton : UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButton.changeUIButtonBorder()
}
```

However, there is no magical way to shoutcast to all UIButtons that they should call that method; you'll have to deal with them one at a time.

The "magical" way is, as @Sh_Khan suggests, to make a UIButton subclass that calls `changeUIButtonBorder` *in its own initializer*. You would then simply have to make sure that all your buttons are instances of that subclass.

For example, here's a UIButton subclass that's always red (assuming that all instances come from the storyboard):

```
class RedButton : UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: NICE!!  I was sooo close!  Thank you!  I see how the initializer is helpful but how would I be able to affect all instances if this isn't a class method?

Comment: The idea is to make the change _automatic_ for class. The initializer is called automatically, so the change happens just by virtue of this being an instance of this class.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I get it now.  Just need to implement it to see for myself.  Thank you so much